# Installing pymc - Lapack issues

Tags: numpy, lapack, pymc, intel-mkl

Hoping someone might have some experience with this issue, I checked google but had no luck even finding the error message.

I'm trying to install pymc (using `pip install --user pymc`) on a server with Wakari and Anaconda python installed.

I am getting back an error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_lapack95_lp64.` I've tried manually setting a location for the LAPACK directory, but this doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to attack this one?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Anaconda installed, why not install the [pymc package](https://conda.anaconda.org/pymc) with the conda package manager?

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/pymc pymc`

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't have access to binstar due to network constraints. I need to figure out a way to link against LAPACK.

Comment: Your network grants access to pypy so you can use pip but not to binstar? Are you able to download the conda package from another machine and transfer it locally?

Comment: ^^ This all depends on whether I can transfer the file over. I'll try but my preference is very much to run with fixing the LAPACK issues! I know I'm likely to run across these again with other packages and would rather fix this (whether it's a problem with environment variables, or something in distutils) than implement a bandaid solution.